# How to send mail from any e-mail address in android?

Tags: android

I want send mail from any email address in android and not specify a gmail email address.

How can this be done? Thanks

Comment: ya i want to send mail from yahoo,rediff etc mail account

Comment: Is this about using the sdk or a question about using your phone?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use

```
public static Intent createChooser (Intent target, CharSequence title
```

(see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

There's a useful snippet in anddev.org: http://www.anddev.org/email_send_intent_intentchooser-t3295.html

It only works in real devices, AFAIK.